# HighCharts: SVG outside plot area

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I am designing an HighCharts bubble chart (a matrix with coloured fields, drawn using SVG), that should have some text explaining the axis values *outside* of the actual chart area.

That is, because the axis values are `A-E` and need a lengthy explanation (`A = Always exceeds goals bla bla` etc.).

These explanations should be visible - next to the chart, not in it, and not in tooltips because these cannot be printed.

My question: Can I put SVG `<text/>` outside of the plot area? HighCharts seems to stretch the plot area as far as it can, leaving no space to either side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text text and define css styles i.e: position:absolute;left:20px;top:20px;

Comment: can I use javascript there as well? Because the position needs to be dynamic (the chart is required to resize based on the user's window size).

Comment: You can catch $(window).resize() function and update div's CSS by .css() function in jquery

Comment: please excuse my ignorance and the delay in answering, but how exactly would I implement what you are saying? Are you talking about adding CSS properties to the chart.renderer.text object inside highcharts? This doesn't seem to work.